# Firefox ESR - only one VM is opened when loading the same applet two times in two different tabs

Tags: java, firefox, applet, jvm

I am using Firefox ESR 10.0.10. When I open the same applet twice in two different tabs only one console is opened. For me it looks like both instances are in the same VM. If I open now a third tab with the same applet a second console is opened, at the fourth tab again not...

What do I have to do to ensure that a new VM is opened for every tab or applet instance respectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See launching a [`SEPARATE_JVM`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/applet/applet_deployment.html#SEPARATE_JVM) for each applet instance.

> A `boolean` parameter specifying that a particular applet should run in its own JVM instance. This supports certain powerful desktop applets which can not tolerate any interference from other applets running in the same JVM and potentially consuming heap space or other resources.

```
<APPLET archive="my_applet.jar" code="MyApplet" width="300" height="300">
    <PARAM name="java_arguments" value="...">
    <PARAM name="separate_jvm" value="true">
</APPLET>
```